# Cannot find wxWebView after wxWidgets installation

Tags: ubuntu, elixir, wxwidgets, phoenix-live-view

### Background

I am trying to run the demo app `desktop-example-app` showed in Elixir Berlin meetup February 2021:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aFpBHQ0YEw4&t=2016s

I have followed all the necessary setup steps from the installation guide for Ubuntu:

- https://hexdocs.pm/desktop/installation.html

```
sudo apt install inotify-tools libtool automake libgmp-dev make libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-dev libssl-dev libncurses5-dev curl git
```

```
sudo apt install libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libssh-dev unixodbc-dev libgmp3-dev libwxbase3.0-dev libwxgtk3.0-gtk3-dev libwxgtk-webview3.0-gtk3-dev libsctp-dev lksctp-tools build-essential libgtk-3-dev libnotify-dev libsecret-1-dev catch

mkdir ~/projects && cd ~/projects
git clone https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets.git
cd wxWidgets; 
git checkout v3.1.5
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/wxWidgets --enable-clipboard --enable-controls \
      --enable-dataviewctrl --enable-display \
      --enable-dnd --enable-graphics_ctx \
      --enable-std_string --enable-svg \
      --enable-unicode --enable-webview \
      --with-expat --with-libjpeg \
      --with-libpng --with-libtiff \
      --with-opengl --with-zlib \
      --disable-precomp-headers --disable-monolithic

make -j4
```

And I have the rest of the dependencies installed via asdf in the project:

```
erlang 24.0
elixir 1.12.2-otp-24
sqlite 3.36.0
nodejs 12.16.1
```

### Problem

The installation went without any issues as far as I can tell. However, when I execute the script `./run` to launch the application, I get the following error:

```
error] Process #PID<0.383.0> terminating
** (exit) {:bad_return, {{TodoApp, :start, [:normal, []]}, {:EXIT, {{:badmatch, {:error, {{:EXIT, {{:badmatch, {:error, {{:undefined_function, {:wxWebView, :new, 0}}, [{:wxe_util, :rec, 1, [file: 'wxe_util.erl', line: 110]}, {Desktop.Fallback, :webview_new, 1, [file: 'lib/desktop/fallback.ex', line: 88]}, {Desktop.Window, :init, 1, [file: 'lib/desktop/window.ex', line: 175]}, {:wx_object, :init_it, 6, [file: 'wx_object.erl', line: 404]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 226]}]}}}, [{Desktop.Window, :start_link, 1, [file: 'lib/desktop/window.ex', line: 103]}, {:supervisor, :do_start_child_i, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 414]}, {:supervisor, :do_start_child, 2, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 400]}, {:supervisor, :handle_start_child, 2, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 706]}, {:supervisor, :handle_call, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 455]}, {:gen_server, :try_handle_call, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 721]}, {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 750]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 226]}]}}, {:child, :undefined, TodoWindow, {Desktop.Window, :start_link, [[app: :todo_app, id: TodoWindow, title: "TodoApp", size: {600, 500}, icon: "icon.png", menubar: TodoApp.MenuBar, icon_menu: TodoApp.Menu, url: &TodoWeb.Endpoint.url/0, app: :todo_app, id: TodoWindow]]}, :permanent, false, 5000, :worker, [Desktop.Window]}}}}, [{TodoApp, :start, 2, [file: 'lib/todo_app.ex', line: 24]}, {:application_master, :start_it_old, 4, [file: 'application_master.erl', line: 293]}]}}}}
    (kernel 8.0) application_master.erl:142: :application_master.init/4
    (stdlib 3.15) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
Initial Call: :application_master.init/4
Ancestors: [#PID<0.382.0>]
Message Queue Length: 1
Messages: [{:EXIT, #PID<0.384.0>, :normal}]
Links: [#PID<0.382.0>, #PID<0.44.0>]
Dictionary: []
Trapping Exits: true
Status: :running
Heap Size: 1598
Stack Size: 29
Reductions: 252
** (Mix) Could not start application todo_app: exited in: TodoApp.start(:normal, [])
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {{:EXIT, {{:badmatch, {:error, {{:undefined_function, {:wxWebView, :new, 0}}, [{:wxe_util, :rec, 1, [file: 'wxe_util.erl', line: 110]}, {Desktop.Fallback, :webview_new, 1, [file: 'lib/desktop/fallback.ex', line: 88]}, {Desktop.Window, :init, 1, [file: 'lib/desktop/window.ex', line: 175]}, {:wx_object, :init_it, 6, [file: 'wx_object.erl', line: 404]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 226]}]}}}, [{Desktop.Window, :start_link, 1, [file: 'lib/desktop/window.ex', line: 103]}, {:supervisor, :do_start_child_i, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 414]}, {:supervisor, :do_start_child, 2, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 400]}, {:supervisor, :handle_start_child, 2, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 706]}, {:supervisor, :handle_call, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line: 455]}, {:gen_server, :try_handle_call, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 721]}, {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 750]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 226]}]}}, {:child, :undefined, TodoWindow, {Desktop.Window, :start_link, [[app: :todo_app, id: TodoWindow, title: "TodoApp", size: {600, 500}, icon: "icon.png", menubar: TodoApp.MenuBar, icon_menu: TodoApp.Menu, url: &TodoWeb.Endpoint.url/0, app: :todo_app, id: TodoWindow]]}, :permanent, false, 5000, :worker, [Desktop.Window]}}}
            (todo_app 0.0.1) lib/todo_app.ex:24: TodoApp.start/2
            (kernel 8.0) application_master.erl:293: :application_master.start_it_old/4
```

I have wxWidgets installed, but it looks like it can't find it. This is my OS version:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
(base) pedro:~/Workplace
```

How can I fix the issue?

### EDIT

I tried checking if I had the `webkitgtk` installed but apparently I don't. I also cannot find the package even though it seems to exist in `packages.ubuntu.com`:

```
(base):~$ dpkg -l webkitgtk
dpkg-query: no packages found matching webkitgtk

(base):~$ sudo apt-get install webkitgtk 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package webkitgtk
```

which is confusing because aparently the name of the package should be correct:
https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=sourcenames&keywords=webkitgtk

Comment: do you have `WebKitGTK` installed?

Comment: How can I verify that?

Comment: @Flamephoenix, yourun `dpkg -l webkitgtk`. Make sure it is a correct name for Ubuntu.

Comment: I have updated my question with this info !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed everything according to the page, I even removed my `asdf` erlang installation to do it. The result wasn't any better. I also installed and compiled wxWidgets from source and yet nothing.

The one thing that ended up saving me was this discussion:
https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang/issues/203

Where they suggest the following commands:

```
asdf plugin-update --all
asdf install erlang 24.0.1
```

Indeed, installing version `24.0.1` with asdf fixed the issue for me.